# Удалить пункт меню в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Нашел где пункты меню хранятся в базе, удалил один, теперь вместо него выводится текст: `#0 (без названия)`. Как пункт удалить полностью?

Comment: лучше бы вы нашли, где меню создаётся в админке. Лезть руками в БД - дурной тон

Comment: Я полагаю речь идёт о панели навигации. Тогда через админ панель его можно удалить. Что бы зайти в админ панель наберите `ваш_сайт\wp_admin`

Answer (score 0):

Откройте панель администратора {www.domain.com}/wp-admin/ -> наведите на пункт меню "Appearance" (не помню как на русском) -> "Menus"

И там будут все меню, можно добавить или удалить пункт, там уже я думаю интуитивно будет понятно

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?